# Ramp in and out SVG turbulence filter

Tags: javascript, svg, filter, graphics

I'm working on a non-linear menu and I'd like it to have a nice animation when hovering over the options. I managed to put together a turbulence svg filter that I like. Now I'm wondering how to make it so that when one hovers over the option the turbulence ramps up progresively, and that the same happens in the opposite direction on mouse out, it slowly fades out.

**What's the most straightforward way of addresing this through js?**

I'm not well acquaintanced with svg filters. Should I directly manipulate the baseFrequency's values? I reckon that would affect all nodes and not just the one being hovered over. Is there any way css can be leveraged? Is there any way to pass arguments into a filter?

Here's the hand-crafted svg filter code along with the -simplified- svg code exported from my design app. I've omitted the circle's stroke data.

```html
<defs>

  <filter filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="turbulence" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feTurbulence id="base_turbulence" numOctaves="3" seed="2" baseFrequency="0.02 0.05"></feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap scale="20" in="SourceGraphic"></feDisplacementMap>
  </filter>

  <animate xlink:href="#base_turbulence" attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="60s" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0.01 0.02;0.02 0.03;0.01 0.03" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</defs>


  <g id="ser" class="node" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,84,88)">
      <g class="circle" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-12,13)" filter="url(#turbulence)">
          <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-179,-8)">
              <circle cx="512.5" cy="229.5" r="53.5" style="fill:rgb(255,235,187);"/>
              <path d="(...)"/>
          </g>
          <g class="marker" transform="matrix(1.24299,0,0,1.24299,-303.533,-63.7664)">
              <path d="(...)"/>
          </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-21.3664)">
          <text x="342px" y="229px" style="font-family:'LibreBaskerville-Regular', 'Libre Baskerville';font-size:47.751px;stroke:rgb(2,2,2);stroke-width:1px;">S<tspan x="379.962px 414.486px " y="229px 229px ">er</tspan></text>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-18.1341,1.72278)">
          <text x="344.149px" y="246px" style="font-family:'LibreBaskerville-Regular', 'Libre Baskerville';font-size:25.202px;stroke:rgb(2,2,2);stroke-width:1px;">El Silencio Donde Escucho</text>
      </g>
  </g>

  <g id="propuestas" class="node" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,137.028,83)">
      <g class="circle" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-126.851,580.865)">
          <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-179,-8)">
              <circle cx="512.5" cy="229.5" r="53.5" style="fill:rgb(187,205,255);"/>
              <path d="(...)"/>
          </g>
          <g class="marker" transform="matrix(1.24299,0,0,1.24299,-303.533,-63.7664)">
              <path d="(...)"/>
          </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-115,543.634)">
          <text x="342px" y="229px" style="font-family:'LibreBaskerville-Regular', 'Libre Baskerville';font-size:47.751px;stroke:rgb(2,2,2);stroke-width:1px;">P<tspan x="381.968px 411.383px 449.775px 489.36px 528.517px 563.041px 591.883px 617.095px 650.712px " y="229px 229px 229px 229px 229px 229px 229px 229px 229px ">ropuestas</tspan></text>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-133.134,566.723)">
          <text x="344.149px" y="246px" style="font-family:'LibreBaskerville-Regular', 'Libre Baskerville';font-size:25.202px;stroke:rgb(2,2,2);stroke-width:1px;">Encuentr<tspan x="463.279px " y="246px ">o</tspan>s, taller<tspan x="571.371px " y="246px ">e</tspan>s, seminarios</text>
      </g>
  </g>
```

I'm targeting circles within nodes to have the effect.

And this is the result as is:

[image: svg turbulence animation]

Thanks!

Comment: Animate some of the turbulence properties using SMIL.

Comment: "that would affect all nodes" - is that supposed to mean you use the same filter in multiple places? Your example has only one place where the filter is used.

Comment: @ccprog yes, I built the conceptual test with two nodes but there could potentially be a dozen or so, and if hover over one and then on another the first one should be ramping down while the latter is ramping up.

Comment: You want separate filters in that case the.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I was starting to suspect that. I've noticed that the svg animate tag supports begin and end attributes. I managed to make the filter activate on mouse enter, but then ending it on mouseleave produces an ugly abrupt stop. I also saw references to SMIL on MDN docs on the animate tag, which suggest the tag implements SMIL?

Comment: I also noted that filters can be switched by css keyframes animations, but that steps through static images in discrete steps and I'm looking for a smooth animation. I wonder whether I can target the filter's baseFrequency from keyframes rules and leverage css interpolation. Will try.

Comment: Hm seems that keyframes cannot target feTurbulence properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to trigger animations of the filter with mouse events. As noted in the comments above, you need to define a separate filter for every target. Take care to always use unique IDs.

The "ramp up" effect is the result of "damping" the alpha channel of the turbulence before it is fed to the displacement map. Alpha values are multiplied with a value between 0 and 1. This value is interpolated to go from the current animated value to 1  after `mouseover` or to 0 after `mouseout`.

The trick is using `additive="sum"` in the `mouseout` animation. It adds to the value the previous animation currently is at. The two animations might run in parallel for some time if they are triggered in short sequence. During that times, the "ramping" stalls, because they are canceling each other out, but it does not jump.

To save on processing power needed, the turbulence animation is also only active while the mouse is hovering over the triggering element, on `mouseout` time plus 1s it is stopped.

The effect is not triggered by the mouse over the filtered element itself, but by an invisible element on top. Otherwise you would get some weird effects because the displacement changes the area where the mouse is considered over the element.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <filter id="turbulence" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
          x="-.5" y="-.5" width="2" height="2">
    <feTurbulence numOctaves="2" seed="3" baseFrequency="0.02 0.05" result="rand">
      <animate id="change" attributeName="baseFrequency"
               begin="dot.mouseover" end="dot.mouseout+1s" dur="60s"
               keyTimes="0;.125;.25;.375;.5;.625;.75;.875;1"
               values="0.013,0.013;0.01,0.02;0.013,0.027;0.02,0.03;0.027,0.027;0.03,0.02;0.027,0.013;0.02,0.01;0.013,0.013"
               repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </feTurbulence>
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0">
        <animate attributeName="slope" begin="dot.mouseover" dur="1s"
                 keyTimes="0;1" values="0;1" fill="freeze" />
        <animate attributeName="slope" begin="dot.mouseout" dur="1s"
                 keyTimes="0;1" values="0;-1" fill="freeze"
                 additive="sum" />
      </feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="20" />
    <feOffset dx="-10" dy="-10" />
  </filter>
  <g style="filter:url(#turbulence)">
      <circle r="60" cy="100" cx="100"
              style="fill:rgb(255, 235, 187);stroke:#999;stroke-width:16" />
      <circle r="60" cy="100" cx="100"
              style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:8" />
  </g>
  <circle id="dot" r="70" cy="100" cx="100" style="opacity:0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's neat! It wouldn't have come to my mind to rely on the alpha channel like that since I wasn't thinking of the turbulence as an image! And the mechanisms for going in and out seem sound too. Thanks!

Comment: It just shades me a bit (haha) that decreasing the baseFrequency changes the direction of movement... is that an artifact?

Comment: You can find the algorithm behiind tubulence [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#feTurbulenceElement). I think you will find that the origin of modulation is always at the top left corner. Increasing the frequency means shortening the length in which variations occur. So it is a deterministic consequence.

Comment: I will check it out || The result is beautiful! Thanks once more, I really appreciate it https://ibb.co/CWVRnrc

Comment: ...or did you comment on the effect that during "ramping" the grafic seems to move a bit left and up? That has nothing to do with turbulence attributes, the ramping is done in the next filter step. The movement effect occurs in the feDisplacementMap step itself and might be caused by [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/113). In short: browser implementations compute displacement values nonlinearily from the color channel values, despite the spec saying otherwise.

Comment: I meant the whole turbulence animation effect seems to have a visual direction to it, which is suddenly and noticeably reversed when the freq parameter changes direction (from increasing to decreasing). I'm conjecturing that I might need to slide i.e. translate the turbulence instead (or on top of) of animating the frequency.

Comment: You are aware that after simple duration the frequency value jumps if the last value is not identical to the first? All SMIL animations are performed like CSS `animation-direction: normal`. Also, I've enhanced my example code to a sort-of "circular" change of the frequency. Is that more what you had in mind?

Comment: The result I posted some comments ago and that stemmed from your solution does fit what I have in mind. I'm just curious about this noticeable effect -which is not a prooblem atm- in which there seems to be movements in opposite directions when one hovers in and out, instead of just the same direction with rising and falling intensity (more like water ripples)